# url mapping based on contains in angular and ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

I am mapping templates

```
.state('tab.details', {
        url: '/details',
        views: {
            'tab-home': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/details.html',
                controller: "controllerName"
            }
        }
    })
```

Now is there a way where I can specify that `url:"/details/*"`, i.e i basically want to map whatever url contains details/ to this controller. For example, my code works when i have `www.mysite.com/#tab/details?querystring` but its going to default page when i have `www.mysite.com/#tab/details/querystring`

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use url parameters `url: '/details/:query'`

You can then access that in the controller by injection `$stateParams` and calling `$stateParams.query`

Answer (score 0):

After implementing Long Nguyen's answer, I faced one more problem

The url changed from

`www.site.com/purchase?ItemId=xxx` to `www.site.com/purchase/xxx`

But i wanted it to change to 
`www.site.com/purchase/item-name/xxx`  (for SEO optimization)

To do that 
I changed the url from `url: '/details/:query'` to `url: '/details/:query/:name'`